# How do I install the new Ubuntu for Windows on Insider Preview 14295?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10

With all the talk today about [Ubuntu on Windows](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11390545), I thought I would give it a whirl in the brand new Insider Preview 14295. Scott Hanselman seems to indicate that it [can be installed](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DevelopersCanRunBashShellAndUsermodeUbuntuLinuxBinariesOnWindows10.aspx), but his blog post is a bit short on specifics:

> After turning on Developer Mode in Windows Settings and adding the Feature, run you bash and are prompted to get Ubuntu on Windows from Canonical via the Windows Store...

I downloaded the Preview build 14295 from MSDN, installed as a Windows Pro version on a clean machine, and went into Settings and enabled Developer Mode.

Now what? How do I "[add] the Feature"? I looked in Programs and Features / Turn Windows features on or off, but don't see anything there about Ubuntu or bash. I searched the Windows Store for Ubuntu and Canonical but no luck there.

Am I just jumping the gun? :-)

Comment: wait until Microsoft provides the steps.

Comment: Aw man. You mean *delayed gratification*? What fun is that? :-)

Comment: Microsoft didn't make it clear when and where it would be available. Maybe it was announced a bit too soon?

Answer (score 1):

Scott Hanselman [answered my question over on Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11394994), so I thought I'd pass his advice along here:

> Builds coming soon first via the Windows Insider Program. Sign up and you'll get it all over Windows Update soon.

Comment: Same here.  Just downloaded the Preview 14295 from MSDN, installed in VB, set to Developer Mode, joined the Insider Program, set to Fast updates. And now I await...  and wait.

Comment: @EricDuncan Could you let us know when it does roll in for you?

Comment: @LennardFonteijn outlined the directions on my blog: http://eduncan911.com/software/how-to-enable-bash-on-windows-10-preview.html

Comment: I signed for insider preview, and changed my settings on my windows 10 vm, but it still says "it will take some time to receive a build after you change your settings...". Can anyone tell me what "some time" means? How long should I expect to wait to receive the build?

Answer (score 1):

The Bash is available since [Build 14316](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/04/06/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14316/)

[image]

> **Run native Bash on Ubuntu on Windows**: In this build, you can natively run Bash in Windows as announced last week at Build 2016. To
>   do this, you first need to **turn on Developer Mode** via **Settings >
>   Update & security > For developers**.
>
> [image]
>
> Then search for “`Windows Features`”
>   and choose “`Turn Windows features on or off`” and enable **Windows
>   Subsystem for Linux (Beta)**. 
>   [image]
>   To get Bash installed, open Command Prompt
>   and type “bash”.

Microsoft explained all steps in detail [in this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/04/06/bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-download-now-3/).